# UIDatePicker and NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have an NSDate that I get from a UIDatepicker.

```
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dueDate;
NSDate *selectedDate = [dueDate date];
```

How do I retrieve the month from `dueDate` in the form of an `int`?  (1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:[dueDate date]];
NSInteger month = [components month];
```

Answer (score 5):

use `-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]` for instance the example here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"%m" allowNaturalLanguage:NO] autorelease];
int month = [[dateFormat stringFromDate:dueDate] intValue];
```