# How can I add just the day of a UIDatePicker to a label - e.g. just "28" when the date selected is "28/10/2011"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, date, uidatepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDatePicker and NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727696/uidatepicker-and-nsdate)

Can I do this and how? I simply need to get the day inputted by the user and put it into a label, rather than the whole date (e.g. old: 28/10/2011 new: 28)

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at `NSDateFormatter?` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I did, and managed to put the full date in, but not just the day :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user input is text you will need to start with an `NSDateFormatter` and then you can extract the day from the calendar components. (I recommend collecting the date through a `UIDatePicker`)

```
//Start here for a date that is a string
NSString *userinput = @"28/10/2011";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:userinput];
[formatter release];

//Start here if you already have an `NSDate` object
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                                               fromDate:date];

NSString *dayForLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components day]];
```

Comment: great, thanks! How would I add the event to the iPhones calendar using the full DatePicker date?

Comment: The instructions for that are in the [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/EditingEventsProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005158-SW1)

Comment: Thanks! Also, I've put this: http://pastie.org/2672944 but the label has a "%" in it rather than the actual day number... Why is this? :)

Comment: You need to format the string with the day, `CalLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components day]];`

Comment: Works now - thanks for your excellent and fast help! :-)

Comment: Would you mind looking at the code I'm using to create an event as it's not working for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718006/xcode-why-is-my-event-not-being-added-to-the-calendar - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
NSDate *date = [picker date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [picker calendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", day];
```