# XCode: Why is my event not being added to the calendar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uidatepicker, eventkit

I have added the following code to my app:

```
NSDate * selected = [DatePicker date];
NSString * date = [selected description];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                                              fromDate:DatePicker.date];

CalLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components day]];

EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
event.title = @"Test Event";
//required
event.startDate = [DatePicker date];
event.endDate = [DatePicker date];
event.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
//end

NSError *err;
[store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Why is this not adding anything to the iOS calendar?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked for an error? If you wrap the saveEvent call in an if not check you can then `NSLog(@"%@", err);` to see why it fails.

Comment: It says: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=3 "No end date has been set." UserInfo=0x178fe0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No end date has been set.}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your event needs a valid time span to save it. Try this

```
event.startDate = selected;
event.endDate = [selected dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*60]; //30 minutes for example
```

Comment: Once again, thank you very much - you've been very very helpful! It all works for me... Much appreciated :-)